# Trying to connect a HTML5 date input with date model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an HTML5 date input element like this:
    `<input type="date" />`

if you choose a date in this input a string will be the value, for example:
`"2018-12-31"`

In my model I want the date to be presented as the following string:
`"2018-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"` and not the simplified string.

How do I make sure that the date in my model keeps the correct format? I tried using a computed but since I am in a loop this time I cannot use them.

```
{{eventDate.date}}
<b-form-input
    v-bind:value="eventDate.date"
    v-on:input="eventDate.date = $event.target.value"
    v-bind:id="'event-day-date-' + index"
    size="sm"
    type="date"
    placeholder="2018-12-31"
>
</b-form-input>
```

As you can see here the eventDate.date is a long string but the input needs the format YYYY-MM-DD. I need to convert it to and from this format some way.
[image]

Comment: Can you show code that you have or already have tried?

Comment: @SuperDJ I added a code example with screenshot of the rendered HTML in the browser.

Comment: Altough this isn't an answer to your question but it's not required to use `v-bind` or `v-on` just `:value` or `@input` is enough

Comment: Yeah I read about that in the docs :). I used the v-on and v-bind to try to work out my problem. But didn't work.

Is the problem now clear to you? If not let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```
filters: {
  dateToString(date) {
    return date.toString().substr(0,10)
  }
}
```

and then update your template

```
:value="eventDate.date | dateToString"
```

Comment: It's `filters` in vue.js 2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
<input
    v-validate="'required'"
    v-bind:name="'eventdate-' + index"
    v-bind:value="eventDate.date | dateToString"
    v-on:input="eventDate.date = $event.target.value + 'T00:00:00.000Z'"
    v-bind:id="'event-day-date-' + index"
    class="form-control form-control-sm"
    type="date"
    placeholder="2018-12-31"
/>
```